# convergence ratio of the serie $e^{xn}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

How can I determine the values of $x$ such that the series converge:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{xn}$$

I'm really lost in this problem, please help.

Comment: It's a geometric series :)

Comment: it is $e^x<1$ then $x<0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is to use the **Root Test.** The $n$-th root of $a_n$ is $e^x$. By the Root Test, your series converges if $e^x\lt 1$, that is, if $x\lt 0$. You also need to check what happens at $x=0$.

**More simply**, your series is a geometric series, with common ratio $e^x$. Now you know that the geometric series $1+t+t^2+t^3+\cdots$ converges precisely if $|t|\lt 1$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Note that $e^{xn} = (e^x)^n$.

Comment: Why was this answer ignored? It's the most natural way to solve the problem.